# Agent (in load testing) test data randomly while data read in sequence

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

Load test read data in sequence but it test that data in random order.
Output of 'transaction order' is random and I want it in sequence.

Comment: Care to clarify?

Comment: I want to enforce my agents to read data according my desire.....I want agent read from let say 1 to 10 rows in sequence, but it read in random order

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask